# how to convert byte pointer to structure

Tags: c#, pointers

i am having a trouble converting a byte pointer to a structure (while it works implicitly when the byte pointer is the argument but it never work with casting to a new object)

assume i've

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct x
    {
        public y;
        public zType;
    }
```

which is a sequential structure that will represent a byte[] so when i can assign that byte[] to this structure and use it like x.y without having to worry about offsets

my problem is when i pass a byte pointer byte* ptr = byte[] to a method with this structure as parameter it works but when i try to cast it normally it doesn't work

```
//this example works fine

{
  byte[] myByteArray = new byte[];
  fixed (byte* ptr = myByteArray)
  someMethod(ptr)
}

someMethod(x myStruct)


//the next example however doesn't work
{
  byte[] myByteArray = new byte[];
  fixed (byte* ptr = myByteArray)
  x myStruct = (myStruct)ptr
}
```

i hope i make sense, any idea how to cast it ?

Comment: @MitchWheat Judging by the attribute, I'm going with C#.

Comment: your sample code have lot of coding error i took that as pseudo code

Comment: yup it's not real code ofc, just snippet to help my poor english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

overload the implicit operator like the following

```
public unsafe static implicit operator X (byte* ptr)
{
  var myX = new x();
  x.y = *((type*)(ptr + offset));
  return myX;
}
```

also overload the byte[] operator to be something like

```
public unsafe static implicit operator byte[] (X myX)
{
  var myBuffer = new byte[size];
  fixed(byte* ptr = myBuffer)
  {
    *((type*)(ptr + offset)) = myX.y;
  }
  return myBuffer;
}
```

now you can pretty much do the following

```
byte[] B = new byte[];
fixed(byte* ptr = B)
{
  X myX = ptr;
  byte[] C = X;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure if this is what you wanted but this is how;

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct x
        {
            public byte y;
            public byte zType;
        }

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
              var myByteArray = new byte[4];
              myByteArray[0] = 1;
              myByteArray[1] = 2;
              myByteArray[2] = 3;
              myByteArray[3] = 4;
              fixed (byte* ptr = myByteArray)
              {
                  var myStruct = (x*)ptr;
                  //myStruct now contain 
                  //myStruct.y == 1
                  //myStruct.ztype == 2

              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did try that and it says "cannot declare pointer to non-unmannaged type 'mystruct type'", that's when i got completely lost :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be... var MyStruct = ((x*)ptr)[0];